# how to run hyperedger/composer-cli docker image to execute composer commands?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-composer

Instead using npm package of composer-cli I want to execute composer commands through docker image. But currently after running the container it immediately exits. Need help to run this container with proper configuration.

Comment: Have you trying to execute `bash -c 'sleep infinity'` as CMD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This command should build the container for you: `docker run  -it --network composer_default   -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer --entrypoint "/bin/sh"  hyperledger/composer-cli:latest`

This will start the container and with an interactive terminal ( `-it` ) and will stay up because of the alternate entrypoint.

Note also that you need to start on the same Docker Bridge as your other Fabric containers, and the development fabric uses `--network composer_default`

You may want to persist the Business Network cards you use so they are available if you have to create a new cli container, so start a shared volume `-v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer`

You also need to be aware that the default development environment assumes that the Fabric can be connected on the address *localhost* - **BUT** this won't work when you are inside a container - so you will need to replace the URLs in the connection.json for the PeerAdmin card to point to the addresses that known to the Docker Bridge.  A `sed` command like this should change the addresses for you.

`sed -e 's/localhost:7051/peer0.org1.example.com:7051/' -e 's/localhost:7053/peer0.org1.example.com:7053/' -e 's/localhost:7054/ca.org1.example.com:7054/'  -e 's/localhost:7050/orderer.example.com:7050/'  < $HOME/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@hlfv1/connection.json  > /tmp/connection.json && cp -p /tmp/connection.json $HOME/.composer/cards/PeerAdmin@hlfv1/`

Finally, if you are using the development Fabric, you will need to create the PeerAdmin Card.